# Filtering rows in R unexpectedly removes NAs when using subset or dplyr::filter

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset, na

I have a dataset `df` and I would like to remove all rows for which variable `y` does not have the value `a`. Variable `y` also contains some `NAs`:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=c('a', NA, 'c'))
```

I can achieve this using R's indexing syntax like this:

```
df[df$y!='a',]

  x    y
  2 <NA>
  3    c
```

Note this returns both the `NA` and the value `c` - which is what I want.

However, when I try the same thing using `subset` or `dplyr::filter`, the `NA` gets stripped out:

```
subset(df, y!='a')

  x    y
  3    c

dplyr::filter(df, y!='a')
  x    y
  3    c
```

Why do `subset` and `dplyr::filter` work like this? It seems illogical to me - an `NA` is not the same as `a`, so why strip out the `NA` when I specifiy I want all rows except those where variable `y` equals `a`?

And is there some way to change the behaviour of these functions, other than explicitly asking for `NAs` to get returned, i.e.

```
subset(df, y!='a' | is.na(y))
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it is by design the default option

Comment: Are you sure that your example of the "correct" behavior, `df[df$y!='a',]` returns what you say it returns? Because I get something different. If we can agree on what returns, I can explain this more fully than just saying "that's the way it is".

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/812 - Romain suggests you proceed explicitly

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Nice answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example of the "expected" behavior doesn't actually return what you display in your question. I get:

```
> df[df$y != 'a',]
    x    y
NA NA <NA>
3   3    c
```

This is arguably *more* wrong than what `subset` and `dplyr::filter` return. Remember that in R, `NA` really is intended to mean "unknown", so `df$y != 'a'` returns,

```
> df$y != 'a'
[1] FALSE    NA  TRUE
```

So R is being told you definitely don't want the first row, you do want the last row, but whether you want the second row is literally "unknown". As a result, it includes a row of all `NA`s.

Many people dislike this behavior, but it is what it is.

`subset` and `dplyr::filter` make a different default choice which is to simply drop the `NA` rows, which arguably is accurate-ish.

But really, the lesson here is that if your data has `NA`s, that just means you need to code defensively around that at all points, either by using conditions like `is.na(df$y) | df$y != 'a'`, or as mentioned in the other answer by using `%in%` which is based on `match`.

---

From `base::Extract`:

> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character `NA` index picks an unknown element and so returns `NA`

From `?base::subset`:

> missing values are taken as false [...] For ordinary vectors, the result is simply `x[subset & !is.na(subset)]`

From `?dplyr::filter`

> Unlike base subsetting with `[`, rows where the condition evaluates to `NA` are dropped

Comment: what do these so called people think `df$y != 'a'` should return? NAs are non-comparable so it cannot return either TRUE or FALSE, and `==` is vectorized so it cannot return something length 2

Comment: @rawr I have no strong feelings on it myself, but I have been involved in and/or witnessed some heated exchanges with people who thought it was bad. I honestly don't recall what they thought the behavior should be.

Comment: Thanks @joran, that explains the behaviour. Re-running my code I see that the result of `df[df$y != 'a',]` is indeed different from what I had in my question, but will leave the q as-is since it's clear from your answer what the 'expected behaviour' should be.

Answer (score 8):

One workaround is to use `%in%`:

```
subset(df, !y %in% "a")
dplyr::filter(df, !y %in% "a")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but will accept @joran's as correct since it gives the full reasoning behind the behaviour as well as pointing to your workaround